# Pytorch's nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss() behaves totaly differently than nn.BCELoss()

Tags: python, pytorch, mse, logits

i'm totally new to pytorch. I was taking an e-course and was experimenting with pytorch. So i came across the two loss functions(The hypothesis for using these two losses is numerical stability with logits):

> nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()

and

> nn.BCELoss()

For appropriate adjustments to the code and these two loss functions, I had quite different accuracy curves!
For example with **nn.BCELoss()** as the below code snippet:

```
model = nn.Sequential(
nn.Linear(D, 1),
nn.Sigmoid()
)

criterion = nn.BCELoss()
```

Accuracy plot was:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRmfI.png)

And for **nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()**, as below:

```
model = nn.Linear(D, 1)
criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
```

Accuracy plot was:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15kVm.png)

The rest of the code is the same for both examples. (Note that, loss curves were similar and decent)
The leaning curves for both snippets were something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UixVZ.png)
I couldn't figure out, what is causing this problem(if there is a bug in my code or something wrong with my pytorch.
Thank you for your time, and help in advance.

Comment: `BCEWithLogitsLoss` "combines a Sigmoid layer and the BCELoss in one single class." That is, you should not have the sigmoid activation before the `BCEWithLogitsLoss` as it's going to add the sigmoid for you. Since you have the sigmoid it's getting applied twice when you compute loss but only once when you compute accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

nn.BCELoss() expects your output to be probabilities, that is with the sigmoid activation.
nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss() expects your output to be logits, that is without the sigmoid activation.

I think maybe you calculated something wrong (like accuracy). Here I give you a simple example based on your code:

With probabilities:

```
dummy_x = torch.randn(1000,1)
dummy_y = (dummy_x > 0).type(torch.float)

model1 = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(1, 1),
    nn.Sigmoid()
)
criterion1 = nn.BCELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model1.parameters(), 0.001)

def binary_accuracy(preds, y, logits=False):
    if logits:
        rounded_preds = torch.round(torch.sigmoid(preds))
    else:
        rounded_preds = torch.round(preds)
    correct = (rounded_preds == y).float()
    accuracy = correct.sum() / len(y)
    return accuracy

for e in range(2000):
    y_hat = model1(dummy_x)
    loss = criterion1(y_hat, dummy_y)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    if e != 0 and e % 100==0:
        print(f"Epoch: {e}, Loss: {loss:.4f}")
        print(f"Epoch: {e}, Acc: {binary_accuracy(y_hat, dummy_y)}")

#Result:
Epoch: 100, Loss: 0.5840
Epoch: 100, Acc: 0.5839999914169312
Epoch: 200, Loss: 0.5423
Epoch: 200, Acc: 0.6499999761581421
...
Epoch: 1800, Loss: 0.2862
Epoch: 1800, Acc: 0.9950000047683716
Epoch: 1900, Loss: 0.2793
Epoch: 1900, Acc: 0.9929999709129333
```

Now with logits

```
model2 = nn.Linear(1, 1)
criterion2 = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
optimizer2 = torch.optim.Adam(model2.parameters(), 0.001)
for e in range(2000):
    y_hat = model2(dummy_x)
    loss = criterion2(y_hat, dummy_y)
    optimizer2.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer2.step()

    if e != 0 and e % 100==0:
        print(f"Epoch: {e}, Loss: {loss:.4f}")
        print(f"Epoch: {e}, Acc: {binary_accuracy(y_hat, dummy_y, logits=True)}")

#Results: 
Epoch: 100, Loss: 1.1042
Epoch: 100, Acc: 0.007000000216066837
Epoch: 200, Loss: 1.0484
Epoch: 200, Acc: 0.01899999938905239
...
Epoch: 1800, Loss: 0.5019
Epoch: 1800, Acc: 0.9879999756813049
Epoch: 1900, Loss: 0.4844
Epoch: 1900, Acc: 0.9879999756813049
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to modify the code according to the loss function (aka criterion) you are using.
For `BCEloss` - Since you are using the sigmoid layer in your model: so the output are between 0 and 1.

For `BCEWithLogitsLoss` - Output is the logit. Logit can be negative or positive. Logit is z, where

```
z = w1*x1 + w2*x2 + ... wn*xn
```

So, for your predictions while using `BCEWithLogitsLoss`, you need to pass this output through a sigmoid layer (For this you can create a small function which returns

```
1/(1+np.exp(-np.dot(x,w)))
```

and then you should calculate the accuracy.

Hope this helps!!!